# Desktop name changed unexpectedly

Tags: 14.04

Why does my ubuntu desktop 14.0.4 say Kali GNU/Linux Desktop?

It used to say Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4. Not anymore, though. Why?

Comment: Think it might be /etc/issue

Comment: `/etc/issue ` shouldn't change randomly, though, especially to another distro

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to change this:

```
my-lat / # cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca \n \l
```

to

```
echo 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS \n \l'>/etc/issue
```